# How to increase memory limit for file_get_contents of 5.8Gbyte zipfile

Tags: php

I am trying to backup 5.9gbyte files in php.
But my code is memory limit.
file_get_contents function is not reading big file such as 3G, 5G zip file.
So i have memory error.
So i tried to split file

```
enter code here
    $in = @fopen($file, "r");
    $path = str_replace($source . '/', '', $file);
     while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
     $zip->addFromString($path, $buff);
    }
```

But this is error about backup of big file when create zip file from big file directory.
Thanks.

Comment: wait, you're zipping 5.8gb with php? Please... do `exec('zip backup.zip file.a file.b file.z')` or a recursive. Don't use php for the zipping, use the native tools. Hell even install 7zip if you're running on windows and use the command line part of it.

Comment: I am trying big file backup in wordpress plugin code

Answer (score 0):

```
post_max_size=0
```

Have a look at this manual it will help you with problems like this one: [guide](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: thanks for your reply, how?

Comment: Top of the php file that you read your data.

Comment: try upload_max_filesize  in case post does not work. You can put any value you want after `=` so i suggest you don't keep it unlimited (for security reasons)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am trying :ini_set('post_max_size',0);

Comment: That's an option or you can change it straight inside your .ini file.

Comment: I am trying again this.:ini_set('post_max_size',0);
                                    ini_set('upload_max_filesize ','5000M');
                                    $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), @file_get_contents($file));

Comment: but it says error:
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 144227184 bytes)

Comment: Ok locate your php.ini file and look for `post_max_size` and change it there. Careful to select the CORRECT php.ini. This will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am making wordpress backup and restore. wp plugin should work anywhere and any condition. so option should be done in code.

Comment: If my answer fits your question don't forget to accept, for other users also.

Comment: thanks, yea. i created php.ini of wp plugin backup php directory. and post_max_size=50000M
it is not working: allowed memory error,sir

Comment: I am trying again:
upload_max_filesize = 10000M
post_max_size = 20000M
memory_limit = 30000M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 1800

Comment: Did you try to set it to unlimited?

Comment: it is error also:
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 144227184 bytes)

Comment: i want 5gbyte zip file creation of file directory

Comment: You said you are using WP. try this 

`define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '10G' );` or just

`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '10G' );`

Comment: thanks, but where should write this?

Comment: Top of the file or find this fields in your .ini file and change them

Comment: thanks, i tried again. but error. and only 372MB backup zip file creation

Comment: Try convert it to MB and add it as MB number. Also your execution time is 3 minutes make sure you don't crush there.

Comment: thanks for your lots of reply. but it is not working in local wp plugin of wordpress